# Facebook Object API create a place with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to create a new **app** object using the [Object API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/). Here's my code...

```
$facebook->api('/app/objects/place', 'post', [
    'access_token' => getFacebookAppToken(),
    'object' => json_encode([
        "title" => $row['title'],
        "image" => "http://www.mydomain.com/images/$id.jpg",
        "url" => "http://www.mydomain.com/?id=$id",
        "description" => $row['ShortDescription'],
        "location:altitude" => '0',
        "location:latitude" => $row['GeoLatitude'],
        "location:longitude" => $row['GeoLongitude']
    ])
]);
```

I'm getting this error...

> OAuthException: (#100) Object Missing a Required Value: Object at URL
>   'http://www.mydomain.com/?id=847' of type 'place' is invalid because
>   a required property 'place:location' of type 'geo_point' was not
>   provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location info should be nested in a "data" array....

```
$facebook->api('/app/objects/place', 'post', [
    'access_token' => getFacebookAppToken(),
    'object' => json_encode([
        "title" => $row['title'],
        "image" => "http://www.mydomain.com/images/$id.jpg",
        "url" => "http://www.mydomain.com/?id=$id",
        "description" => $row['ShortDescription'],
        "data" => [
           "altitude" => '0',
           "latitude" => $row['GeoLatitude'],
           "longitude" => $row['GeoLongitude']
        ]
    ])
]);
```